# How to make use of LotV pre-order beta?

Tags: starcraft-2

I pre-ordered the LotV and now I want to play the beta. How do I do that? I've searched the UI but all it says is "Playing Heart of the Swarm".

Great, now how do I change that to the LotV beta?

It promises direct access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option should appear in your Battle.net app.

Froam a Blizzard e-mail:

> To download the beta, head to the StarCraft II section of the Battle.net® desktop app (select Region / Account > Beta: Legacy of the Void), (...).
>
> Note that for this beta, you'll need to create a new Character name, and your Friends List will not carry over from our other games.